# Pretty printing JSON

Tags: code-golf, string, json

I want format a JSON string into human-readable form. A string like this:

```
'{"foo":"hello","bar":"world","c":[1,55,"bye"]}'
```

would be formatted as:

```
{
  "foo": "hello",
  "bar": "world",
  "c": [
    1,
    55,
    "bye"
  ]
}
```

**Rules:**

1. For objects and arrays properties and items should be starting in
   new line with indent of +2 as you see in the above mentioned
   example.
2. Space after colon is mandatory
3. This is `code-golf`. Shortest code in bytes wins!

please be aware that json string should be part of the answer (but we will omit that from number of bytes, example:

```
echo '{"foo":"hello","bar":"world","c":[1,55,"bye"]}'|npx json
```

will be counted as 14 bytes => `echo |npx json` after omitting the string

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833)! For future reference, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main. I've voted to close your challenge as unclear, as the specifications on how to "pretty print" aren't clear. For example, what if one of the objects is a list/dict, rather than being a string (e.g. `{'a':{'b':'c', 'd':'e'}, 'f':[1,2,3]}`)

Comment: thank you for your feedback! I've extended the question to include array and description

Comment: Another recommendation is to describe "JSON". Link to the JSON website, and put at least a partial description.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
⎕JSON⍠'Compact'0⍣2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVK9gf79HvQvUnfNzCxKTS9QNHvUuNvqf9qhtwqPevkddzY961zzq3XJovfGjtolA5cFBzkAyxMMz@H@agnq1Ulp@vpKVUkZqTk6@ko5SUmIRkFeeX5STAuQlK1lFG@qYmgLFK1OVYmvVAQ)

`⎕JSON` is the built-in to/from JSON converter

`⍠` sets options, here:

`'Compact'` is switched off (`0`)

`⍣2` does the conversion twice (JSON string to APL array, from APL array to JSON string)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 11 bytes

```
-mjson.tool
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1opLT9fyUopIzUnJ19JRykpsQjIK88vykkB8pKVrKINdUxNgeKVqUqxtf///8svKMnMzyv@r5ubVZyfp1eSn58DAA) Note that due to the way TIO works, the code goes in the command line options area and the input goes in the code area.

Comment: Wouldn't this be "Python 3 + `-mjson.tool`" and 0 bytes?

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly I don't think so, because `python -mjson.tool` isn't a programming language since it can only do one task

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly well, I guess the `-m` is the command-line flag here, and the `json.tool` is a builtin command?

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 24 bytes

```javascript
o=>JSON.stringify(o,0,2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/f1s4r2N9Pr7ikKDMvPTOtUiNfx0DHSPN/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmka1Ulp@vpKVUkZqTk6@ko5SUmIRkFeeX5STAuQlK1lFG@qYmgLFK1OVYms1Nf8DAA)

Comment: I think the input is supposed to be a string.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>39</s> 35 bytes

```
s=>JSON.stringify(eval('_='+s),0,2)
```

*Saved 4 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563).*

```js
f=
s=>JSON.stringify(eval('_='+s),0,2)

console.log(f('{"foo":"hello","bar":"world","c":[1,55,"bye"]}'))
```

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcixCsIwEADQf7klCcZSwS6F@AEOOnQUkZgmNeXISa5UivjtMeN7s10tuxzfyz7R6Eswhc3pPFwvDS85pimGTfrVohQPI3asdKuPqjhKTOgbpEkGKb4QiKCHl0ck0PC0uepDGccqB/3toLuu/ubh/hNKlT8)

Answer (score 0):

## Java + Android, 41 bytes

```
s->new org.json.JSONObject(s).toString(2)
```